# How to use FletApp widget in Flutter

Tags: python, flutter, flet

Can anybody tell me how to use the FletApp widget in Flutter? I am using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flet) package from pub dev. I followed everything they are saying by which I can use the flet app in flutter but it gives me an error saying `open libmigui.so failed! dlopen - dlopen failed: library "libmigui.so" not found`. I am trying to run the app in redmi 9 power device which has android 32. Please tell me what should be the structure of the app and how to run it in flutter.